# Proper format when dynamically creating namedtuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, dynamic-memory-allocation, namedtuple

I have created a namedtuple and am using it for tracking individual datasets. When I add a new "data point" to the namedtuple, the print() function shows that I don't have the same exact information. Here is an example:

```
from collections import namedtuple
bbnr = namedtuple('bbnr', ['SN', 'ptr', 'type2'])
DVCS = bbnr('AB01', 101, 'bbnr')
DVCS_b = [DVCS]
print(DVCS_b)  # produces [bbnr(SN='AB01', ptr=101, type2='bbnr')]

DVCS = DVCS, bbnr('AB02', 105, 'bbnr')
DVCS_b = [DVCS]
print(DVCS_b)  # [(bbnr(SN='AB01', ptr=101, type2='bbnr'), bbnr(SN='AB02', ptr=105, type2='bbnr'))]
```

Note in the second printed output that there is an extra set of parentheses () around the entire tuple within the brackets.

How can I be consistent with adding new elements to a namedtuple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not related to named tuples; you are creating those just fine.

Instead, you created a tuple here:

```
DVCS = DVCS, bbnr('AB02', 105, 'bbnr')
```

Note the comma; tuples are defined by the comma, not the parentheses:

```
>>> 1
1
>>> 1,
(1,)
>>> 1, 2
(1, 2)
```

You then wrapped that tuple into a list object.

If you wanted a list of these values, then just create the list:

```
DVCS_b = [DVCS, bbnr('AB02', 105, 'bbnr')]
```

or create the new named tuple without the `DVCS` value and take the previous named tuple you created from the existing list:

```
DVCS = bbnr('AB02', 105, 'bbnr')]
DVCS_b = DVCS_b + [DVCS]
```

or append it to the existing list:

```
DVCS = bbnr('AB02', 105, 'bbnr')]
DVCS_b.append(DVCS)
```

Comment: That was very helpful! When I use "DVCS_b = DVCS_b + [DVCS]", am I creating a list with a tuple as the component? The overall goal is for me to be able to use expressions such as "[x.ptr for x in DVCS_b[0:1]]" in order to index elements within the tuple.

Comment: @StephenD: yes, you are creating a new list object by concatenating the existing list object with another; each element is an instance of your named tuple.

Comment: @StephenD: you can then loop over those and access attributes on each one.